# Customize WYSIHTML5 Toolbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wysihtml5, x-editable

How do you customize the toolbar in [WYSIHTML5](http://xing.github.io/wysihtml5/).  I want to disable the font size and image insert buttons, particularly for the WYSIHTML5 version used in Bootstrap X-editable.

Answer (score 20):

If you happen to use [bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg](https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg) (which is for example used by gem [bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails)), since version 3.0, you will need to nest it inside toolbar :

```
$('#some-textarea').wysihtml5({
  toolbar: {
    "font-styles": true, // Font styling, e.g. h1, h2, etc.
    "emphasis": true, // Italics, bold, etc.
    "lists": true, // (Un)ordered lists, e.g. Bullets, Numbers.
    "html": false, // Button which allows you to edit the generated HTML.
    "link": true, // Button to insert a link.
    "image": true, // Button to insert an image.
    "color": false, // Button to change color of font
    "blockquote": true, // Blockquote
    "size": <buttonsize> // options are xs, sm, lg
  }
});
```

Answer (score 13):

You can disable toolbar options using startup parameters:

```
$('#[YOUR INPUT ID]').wysihtml5({
     "font-styles": false, //Font styling, e.g. h1, h2, etc.
     "emphasis": true, //Italics, bold, etc.
     "lists": true, //(Un)ordered lists, e.g. Bullets, Numbers.
     "html": true, //Button which allows you to edit the generated HTML.
     "link": true, //Button to insert a link.
     "image": false, //Button to insert an image.
     "color": true //Button to change color of font
});
```

This info should be pasted in the tag:

```
<head>
   <script> HERE </scrip>
</head>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do it through CSS

```
ul.wysihtml5-toolbar li a[title="Insert image"] { display: none; }
ul.wysihtml5-toolbar li.dropdown { display: none; }
```