# customizing bootstrap-wysihtml5 text editor with more features

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg

i am using bootstrap-wysihtml5 as per the recommendation & suggestion of most of the people world wide. but i am finding many of the features missing in its tool bar,like adding table,smiles, changing font name, view as a code etc.
http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/
how to add and customize the toolbar so that i my it up and customize the toolbar with additional features up to my requirement.

Comment: You could simply use http://ckeditor.com/ it's open source, easy to use and highly configurable.

Answer (score 1):

Wysihtml5 is kept simple on purpose, to keep it lightweight. For example, as of now there is no plan to add HTML table support (See [this Github issue for Wysihtml5 itself](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/issues/68)).

It is possible to include a View as HTML option, see [this StackOverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305497/customize-wysihtml5-toolbar).

As mentioned in another answer, if you need more sophisticated options, you might want to look at a different editor.